# Drupal 9: implementing custom functionality in PHP

Tags: php, drupal

I would really appreciate it if somebody would give me some hints about implementing/inserting custom functionality into a drupal 9 page with PHP code.
I am trying to write a PHP function that is generating a file based on some specific properties of Drupal users on a button click, and I do not know where to start.
I am really confused. Is there an easy way to insert PHP code into a Drupal basic page?
I am searching for solutions, but what I always find is custom modules where none of the given examples is working

Comment: Start by the beginning, create your own custom module. You need to learn how drupal works and do things the drupal way.

Comment: if you use a custom theme you could also use all kind of hooks in the `xxx.theme` file

Comment: Start with the basics for modules: https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules
Or learn how to work with git and checkout an example code: https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/step-by-step-tutorial-hello-world

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to you to start from the basics. If you need some custom code based on Users' information, you will need to create a custom module.

Try to watch tutorials from Drupalize.me
https://drupalize.me/series/module-development-guide

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you could start creating a new folder inside `web/modules/custom/` with your module name. Something like: `web/modules/custom/my_custom_module`

You should need these files to start:

- *my_custom_module*.info.yml
- *my_custom_module*.routing.yml

---

### *my_custom_module*.info.yml

```
name: my_custom_module
type: module
description: 'Defines my_custom_module functionality'
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
package: Custom
```

### *my_custom_module*.routing.yml

```
my_custom_module.hello_world:
  path: '/hello-world'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_custom_module\Controller\MyCustomClass::helloWorld'
    _title: 'Display an Hello World'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

### src/Controller/MyCustomClass.php

Inside your custom module folder, create this structure of folders `src/Controller/` and the name of the class you want, in this example is `MyCustomClass.php`
We'll extend from ControllerBase and will be sufficient to allow us to create custom functionalities.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_custom_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MyCustomClass extends ControllerBase {

  public function helloWorld() {
    return new Response("Hello World");
  }
}
```

It could be a good point to start learning and developing.